# Removing intersect or overlap of points in the same vector layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, point, geometry, duplication

Is there anyway to remove the intercept part of the vector points?

[image: Circled part shows intercept points]

P.S. Please ignore the red circle, it's not a polygon, it is a hand drawn by me to show the error part

So far I've done: "Select by location" and Geometries Checking. But there isn't a way to work.

Comment: What do you mean with "intercept part of the vector points"? Points are just points, they cannot intersect partially. It is on on off. But you seem to have points which are so close that their symbols, the brows circles, overlap. Is that your problem?

Comment: @user30184 What I meant is that some points are touching each other, ignore the red circle which is drawn by me to show the focus of the picture

Comment: Do you still mean the brown filled circles which are used as point symbols for making the points visible on the map? The point itself does not have dimensions. If point is at coordinates 1,1 only other points at the same 1,1 coordinates intersect with it.

Comment: Do you have postgis?

Comment: @user30184 I see, then what can I do for that then. Hmmm

Comment: @BERA Nope, my company are using QGIS as it's open sourced

Comment: I thought postgis was open source aswell. Doesnt matter, I found DBscan clustering in QGIS :). I had the SQL code ready

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing it, which could work:

1. DBscan Clustering to give each cluster of nearby points a cluster ID, adjust maximum distance:
   [image]
2. Delete duplicates by attribute by cluster ID:
   [image]